# Python - Mirror a data set

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a data set, with XYZ cooridnate values and a scalar value at each X Y Z coordinate. I am looking to mirror this on YZ plane, and then XY plane.

I was able to do this, by manually reading everything into a list or numpy array, creating a new array for each mirror. HOwever, that is not efficient. Wondering if pandas can be used, or if there is an other library, that is useful to have this job done.

As an example, if I have a dataset as follows

```
Scalar X Y Z

123    1 1 1
```

My result should be the following, in a csv or excel:

```
Scalar  X Y  Z
123     1 1  1
123    -1 1  1
123    -1 1 -1
123     1 1 -1
```

Comment: ok but why do you have duplicates over the planes?

Comment: I did not get you, could you elaborate?

Comment: I meant why are values XY and YZ repeated for the same Scalar. can you explain the output?

Comment: The input in my question, is a result of a CFD simulation. This simulation was conducted with symmetric assumption on two planes. 
 The output from this mirroring (question), will be an input for another CFD particle simulation, which won't have any symmetry, but will be a 3D simulation analysis.

Comment: ok, sorry i am not well informed with CFD simulation. It will be great if you update the question with more explanation about how you get to your desired output in data terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dataframe (from what I understand), you can `append` (multiple times) modified copies of the dataframe, changing each time one or more columns of your choosing by using `df.assign`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'scalar': [123] * 3, 'sym': 'None',
                   'x': np.ones(3), 'y': np.ones(3),'z': np.ones(3)})
df.head()
>>scalar    sym     x   y   z
0   123     None    1.0     1.0     1.0
1   123     None    1.0     1.0     1.0
2   123     None    1.0     1.0     1.0

df.append(df.assign(x=-df['x'], sym='yz')).append(df.assign(y=-df['y'], sym='xz'))

>>  scalar  sym     x   y   z
0   123     None    1.0     1.0     1.0
1   123     None    1.0     1.0     1.0
2   123     None    1.0     1.0     1.0
0   123     yz  -1.0    1.0     1.0
1   123     yz  -1.0    1.0     1.0
2   123     yz  -1.0    1.0     1.0
0   123     xz  1.0     -1.0    1.0
1   123     xz  1.0     -1.0    1.0
2   123     xz  1.0     -1.0    1.0
```